# How do I update a table from three stored procedure data queries?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-update

How do I setup a stored procedure to generate a single row with the return data from the three stored procedures?

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GenerateLatestInventory] 
    @CustID int 
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    TRUNCATE TABLE [dbo].[SalesReportTemp]

    INSERT INTO [dbo].[SalesReportTemp](CustomerNumber, MargaritaOnShelf, StrawberryOnShelf, MojitoOnShelf, MoscowOnShelf, SweetTeaOnShelf, JPunchOnShelf)
        EXEC [dbo].[sp_InvOnShelf] @CustID

    INSERT INTO [dbo].[SalesReportTemp](CustomerNumber, MargaritaOnSold, StrawberryOnSold, MojitoOnSold, MoscowOnSold, SweetTeaOnSold, JPunchOnSold)
        EXEC [dbo].[sp_InvOnSold] @CustID
 
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[SalesReportTemp](CustomerNumber, MargaritaOnStart, StrawberryOnStart, MojitoOnStart, MoscowOnStart, SweetTeaOnStart, JPunchOnStart)
        EXEC [dbo].[sp_InvOnStart] @CustID

    SELECT * FROM SalesReportTemp
END
```

Currently, this general, combined Stored Procedure generates the data in three rows:

```
Id  CustomerNumber  InventoryDate   JPunchOnShelf   JPunchOnSold    JPunchOnStart   MargaritaOnShelf    MargaritaOnSold MargaritaOnStart    MojitoOnShelf   MojitoOnSold    MojitoOnStart   MoscowOnShelf   MoscowOnSold    MoscowOnStart   StrawberryOnShelf   StrawberryOnSold    StrawberryOnStart   SweetTeaOnShelf SweetTeaOnSold  SweetTeaOnStart
1   26549   NULL    25  NULL    NULL    20  NULL    NULL    30  NULL    NULL    5   NULL    NULL    15  NULL    NULL    18  NULL    NULL
2   26549   NULL    NULL    11  NULL    NULL    16  NULL    NULL    6   NULL    NULL    31  NULL    NULL    21  NULL    NULL    18  NULL
3   26549   NULL    NULL    NULL    36  NULL    NULL    36  NULL    NULL    36  NULL    NULL    36  NULL    NULL    36  NULL    NULL    36
```

My goal is to get a single row, in this manner:

```
Id  CustomerNumber  InventoryDate   JPunchOnShelf   JPunchOnSold    JPunchOnStart   MargaritaOnShelf    MargaritaOnSold MargaritaOnStart    MojitoOnShelf   MojitoOnSold    MojitoOnStart   MoscowOnShelf   MoscowOnSold    MoscowOnStart   StrawberryOnShelf   StrawberryOnSold    StrawberryOnStart   SweetTeaOnShelf SweetTeaOnSold  SweetTeaOnStart
1   26549   2023-03-21 14:03:53.0000000 25  11  36  20  16  36  30  6   36  5   31  36  15  21  36  18  18  36
```

Comment: **Side note**: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: Put your 3 rows into a temp table, then select the data as you want into your actual table.

Comment: @Dale,  currently, the GenerateLatestInventory is doing just that: SalesReportTemp table is being used for the three stored procedures.  I queried the final table with a * and received the three rows.  How should I query the SalesReportTemp  table to get one single row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to aggregate the values, by customernumber

```
SELECT
  CustomerNumber,  MAX(InventoryDate) as InventoryDate,
  MAX(InventoryDate) as InventoryDate,
  MAX(JPunchOnSold) as JPunchOnSold,
  MAX(JPunchOnStart) as JPunchOnStart,
  MAX(MargaritaOnShelf) as MargaritaOnShelf,
  MAX(MargaritaOnSold) as MargaritaOnSold,
  MAX(MargaritaOnStart) as MargaritaOnStart,
  MAX(MojitoOnShelf) as MojitoOnShelf,
  MAX(MojitoOnSold) as MojitoOnSold,
  MAX(MojitoOnStart) as (MojitoOnStart,
  MAX(MoscowOnShelf) as MoscowOnShelf,
  MAX(MoscowOnSold) as MoscowOnSold,
  MAX(MoscowOnStart) as MoscowOnStart,
  MAX(StrawberryOnShelf) as StrawberryOnShelf,
  MAX(StrawberryOnSold) as StrawberryOnSold,
  MAX(StrawberryOnStart) as StrawberryOnStart,
  MAX(SweetTeaOnShelf) as SweetTeaOnShelf,
  MAX(SweetTeaOnSold) as SweetTeaOnSold,
  MAX(SweetTeaOnStart) as SweetTeaOnStart    
FROM SalesReportTemp
GROUP BY CustomerNumber
```